# Android toolbar Alignment issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-toolbar

Even though there's no subtitle in my Toolbar, the title is shifted to top. How can I align it with navigation icon?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha"
            android:gravity="top"
            app:title="Hello title"
            android:background="@drawable/citylook"/>
```

[image: Issue image]

Comment: try to change gravity to center

Comment: The title comes in center if I change gravity to center

Comment: dude use center|left use | operator for it. simple

Comment: It centers vertically in the whole view, ie vertically center in banner.

Answer (score 0):

You should assing a `minHeight` to your Toolbar.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">
```

Comment: No change. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue recently and managed to find the solution. I hope that'll fix yours too. I just paste the link here 'cause I'm lazy: [Android Toolbar: title and overflow menus aligment issue on 5.0 only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31785410/android-toolbar-title-and-overflow-menus-aligment-issue-on-5-0-only)
Basically, if you are launching the application on a Lollipop device, there is no need to set an Activity with no ActionBar and replace it with a Toolbar: you have to code different themes and layouts for pre-Lollipop and Lollipop devices.
Let me now if that works for you as well!